# How do I debug quartz not triggering my jobs - Quartz Plugin 1.0.1/1.0.2 & Grails 2.2.5

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler, grails-2.0

We have 2 Grails apps running on 2.2.5 because of a few dependencies on old plugins. Both have Quartz installed while the one runs as expected the other doesn't.

In debugging I've removed everything and left it basically as the example:

```
package test

public class TestJob{

    static triggers = {
        simple startDelay: 60000, repeatInterval: 1000
    }

    public def execute(){
        log.error "help me"
    }

}
```

So no great shakes there but for love nor money that log won't display.

If I run:

```
TestJob.triggerNow()
```

I get:

```
2014-12-23 14:22:27,685 [quartzScheduler_Worker-1] DEBUG listeners.SessionBinderJobListener  - Persistence session is opened.
Error |
2014-12-23 14:22:27,686 [quartzScheduler_Worker-1] ERROR test.TestJob  - help me

2014-12-23 14:22:27,686 [quartzScheduler_Worker-1] DEBUG listeners.SessionBinderJobListener  - Persistence session is flushed
```

Which is as expected so I know that the output is making it to the log stream and that it isn't throwing some silent exception.

Also when I start the application I get the following as output:

```
2014-12-23 14:24:54,282 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG quartz.QuartzGrailsPlugin  - Scheduled Job Classes count: 2
```

So I know that the Scheduler is picking them up but it just appears not to execute them.

From config.groovy:

```
quartz {
    autoStartup = true
    jdbcStore = false
    waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown = true
    exposeSchedulerInRepository = false

    props {
        scheduler.skipUpdateCheck = true
    }
}
```

I've tried running this job in the other 2.2.5 application and it executes without fail so I'm actually at a loss as what the problem is and have no idea how to take the debugging further.

I've also turned on logs for:

```
trace             'grails.plugins.quartz', 'grails.app.jobs'
```

But that doesn't really give much in the way of output.

I've done or the usual clean and deleting the .slcache just to be sure but I'm pretty stuck now.

Your suggestions to aid in debugging would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Confirm that you do not have `quartz.autoStartup = false` in your Config.groovy file and add `debug 'grails.plugins.quartz.QuartzGrailsPlugin'` to your logger.

Hope this helps!

Thanks,
SA

Comment: Thanks for the help. I can confirm that autoStartup is set to true (I've edited my original question to reflect as much). I have added the extra log but nothing more is getting logged.

Comment: Is this happening on fresh grails app 2.2.5?

Comment: No, it works on both fresh 2.2.5 app and as mentioned another 2.2.5 application with a similar configuration. I'm not saying there is a problem with Grails or the plugin as clearly the other app proves that it does work I'm just trying to find out how to debug the problem further.